# What is the purpose of a water line reservoir on a fridge?

Tags: refrigerator, water-filtration, samsung

I'm looking at a leaking part from the fridge that came with my house a Samsung RH25H5611SR/AA. The part that's broke is [DA81-05886A](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/samsung-a-s-case-da81-05886a-ap5781884.html) a $140 part, but only the upper tank is bad.

[image: RH25H5611SR/AA]

The upper cylinder (not the filter mount) is leaking. What does that even do? It looks like it's some kind of reservoir bottle that's dried out and cracked. Can this be bypassed? I just want to understand the function of it. My fridge has filtered water provided by an external reverse osmosis unit, so I think I can just bypass this in-fridge filter, but I'm not sure about this piece that I presume is a reservoir. You can see someone fixing it in [this video](https://youtu.be/Nh_6mqqJHrU?t=506).

---

I broke off the filter housing by cutting the water lines on the back you can see the cracked tank here,

[image: Water reservoir]

The piece in question has writing on it that says,

```
CASE-WATER TANK
DA61-05571A
>PP< CAVITY NO #3
MICROFILTER CO. LTD
```

Still not sure why my fridge needs this piece or what happens if I simply bypass it.

Comment: Well, you most certainly need a reservoir if you want *cold* water.  That's the whole point of running water into the fridge, other than for ice, of course.   I recommend going online and getting the full explosion diagram for your fridge so you can see what the design water paths are from inlet to icemaker and cold water outlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by [Carl Witthoft](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/21276/carl-witthoft) was right on this one:

> Well, you most certainly need a reservoir if you want *cold* water.  That's the whole point of running water into the fridge, other than for ice, of course.

The deal here is that water passes through the filter fills up the reservoir and then gets fed into the freezer for cold water, because on this model fridge the water dispenser is on the freezer's side.

So if I bypass this, I'll have a water dispenser but it probably won't be cold.

---

For a follow up, [I'm looking at creating my own](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49826/what-is-the-best-way-to-tap-a-tube-into-a-cylindrical-canister) since this is really gross (if not even hazardous) and can not be cleaned. I order a replacement that was used from eBay and it came in bad condition too, with cracks and mold.

Comment: Right. My fridge has a coil of tubing instead, but the idea is the same--increased volume when it's needed.